# Данные в БД есть, но ошибка: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: node.js, sqlite, node-modules

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const db = new sqlite3.Database(`./datebases/трьч.db`, sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY);
const week = ["Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", "Пятница", "Суббота"];
db.serialize(() => {
  for (var ever = 0; ever < 6; ever++) {
    db.each(`SELECT rowid FROM ${week[ever]}`, (err, row) => {
      console.log(`${row.id} and ${row._8A}`);
    })
  }
})
```

В базе данных записаны данные и эти таблицы. get, all не помогают.
`console.log(err);` пишет `console.log(${row.id} and ${row._8A});  TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Comment: Может ошибку пробовать прочитать `console.log(err)`?

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/Control-Flow#databaseserializecallback "This means that at most one statement object can execute a query at a time. Other statements wait in a queue until the previous statements are executed."

Comment: Я убрал db.serialize(), но всё равно выводит ту же ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы показываете рабочий кусок кода, это можно проверить:

Создаю базу данных, таблицы и наполняю данными:

```js
const path = require('path');
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

const filepath = path.join(__dirname, 'datebases', 'трьч.db');
const db = new sqlite3.Database(filepath);

const week = ['Понедельник', 'Вторник', 'Среда', 'Четверг', 'Пятница', 'Суббота'];

db.serialize(() => {
  for (let daynumber = 0; daynumber < week.length; daynumber += 1) {
    const tablename = week[daynumber];
    db.run(`CREATE TABLE ${tablename} (info TEXT)`);
    db.run(`INSERT INTO ${tablename} (info) VALUES ('${Math.random()}')`);
    db.run(`INSERT INTO ${tablename} (info) VALUES ('${Math.random()}')`);
  }
});
```

Запускаю ваш код:

```
const path = require('path');
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

const filepath = path.join(__dirname, 'datebases', 'трьч.db');
const db = new sqlite3.Database(filepath, sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY);

const week = ['Понедельник', 'Вторник', 'Среда', 'Четверг', 'Пятница', 'Суббота'];

db.serialize(() => {
  for (let daynumber = 0; daynumber < week.length; daynumber += 1) {
    const tablename = week[daynumber];
    db.each(`SELECT rowid FROM ${tablename}`, (err, row) => {
      console.log(daynumber, tablename, err, row, row.rowid, row.id, row._8A);
    });
  }
});
```

Вижу в консоли:

```bsh
0 Понедельник null { rowid: 1 } 1 undefined undefined
0 Понедельник null { rowid: 2 } 2 undefined undefined
1 Вторник null { rowid: 1 } 1 undefined undefined
1 Вторник null { rowid: 2 } 2 undefined undefined
2 Среда null { rowid: 1 } 1 undefined undefined
2 Среда null { rowid: 2 } 2 undefined undefined
3 Четверг null { rowid: 1 } 1 undefined undefined
3 Четверг null { rowid: 2 } 2 undefined undefined
4 Пятница null { rowid: 1 } 1 undefined undefined
4 Пятница null { rowid: 2 } 2 undefined undefined
5 Суббота null { rowid: 1 } 1 undefined undefined
5 Суббота null { rowid: 2 } 2 undefined undefined
```

<sub>Проверено на macOS 10.14.6, nodejs v15.9.0, sqlite_version 3.30.1, пакет sqlite3 v5.0.2</sub>

---

Опыт подсказывает мне, что вы показали не весь код и ошибка происходит в коде, который вы не показали.

Comment: Да, действительно ваш код работал, просто я немного изменил структуру вашего кода. Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: @Svetoslav пометьте ответ принятым, если он вам помог